# Deploying application to heroku porting issue

Tags: go, heroku

I've created rest api in Golang, I am trying to deploy it to Heroku.
It works fine on localhost. I am getting this issue

```
2021-04-15T13:29:02.748892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-04-15T13:29:02.818829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-04-15T13:29:02.908143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-04-15T13:29:03.094090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Is my port not correct or?

`http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)`

Comment: You have to bind the HTTP listener to the port specified by the `PORT` environment variable, access it with `port := os.Getenv("PORT")`

Comment: @icza I did that, `serverPort := os.Getenv("PORT")` `http.ListenAndServe(serverPort, router)`  and still gettin the same issue, in `.env` PORT="3000"

Comment: `ListenAndServe()` expects an _address_ to listen on, not just a port! Please do check the accepted answer on the marked dupliate.